# iPhone: Play sound when in Silent mode iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, avaudioplayer

I've read many posts and articles and am having no luck playing audio when iPhone is in silent. I'm using `react-native-sound` which uses `AVAudioPlayer` under the hood. The following calls succeed without any luck with sound coming through when in silent.

```
  NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
  BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
  if (!success) { /* handle the error condition */ }

  NSError *activationError = nil;
  success = [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
  if (!success) { /* handle the error condition */ }
```

Any suggestions?

Resources:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1668/_index.html

Comment: What you want to achieve? Do you want to play audio when your phone is on silent mode?

Comment: Yes. Playback of sound when phone is in silent is the desired feature.

Answer (score -1):

I am struggling with this as well. I don't think it is totally possible. I can have sound play in silent mode when the app is in foreground then continue playing while it is in the background, but I don't think iOS allows you to trigger a sound to play while the app is in the background and in silent mode. I am using local notifications to trigger the sound to play.

Some people have had luck setting 'Application does not run in background' to YES in the info.plist which keeps the app in the foreground when someone locks there phone with the app still in the foreground but I need the app to work if the phone is locked when the app is in the background.

Currently the only solutions I know of are to play a silent audio track then tell it to keep it active after playing (to not waste cpu/battery). See link [here](https://yifan.lu/2013/12/17/unlimited-backgrounding-on-ios/). Apple normally doesn't approve of this in app review. Or to use location updates.